# "MD5 decrypt" php function to MySQL stored function

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, md5, stored-functions

I'm trying to fix things on a PHP site. There is a pair of PHP functions:

```
function get_rnd_iv($iv_len) {
        $iv = '';
        while ($iv_len-- > 0) {
                $iv .= chr(mt_rand() & 0xff);
        }
        return $iv;
}
function md5_encrypt($plain_text, $password, $iv_len = 16) {
        $plain_text .= "\x13";
        $n = strlen($plain_text);
        if ($n % 16) $plain_text .= str_repeat("\0", 16 - ($n % 16));
        $i = 0;
        $enc_text = get_rnd_iv($iv_len);
        $iv = substr($password ^ $enc_text, 0, 512);
        while ($i < $n) {
                $block = substr($plain_text, $i, 16) ^ pack('H*', md5($iv));
                $enc_text .= $block;
                $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $password;
                $i += 16;
        }
        return base64_encode($enc_text);
}
function md5_decrypt($enc_text, $password, $iv_len = 16) {
        $enc_text = base64_decode($enc_text);
        $n = strlen($enc_text);
        $i = $iv_len;
        $plain_text = '';
        $iv = substr($password ^ substr($enc_text, 0, $iv_len), 0, 512);
        while ($i < $n) {
                $block = substr($enc_text, $i, 16);
                $plain_text .= $block ^ pack('H*', md5($iv));
                $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $password;
                $i += 16;
        }
        return preg_replace('/\\x13\\x00*$/', '', $plain_text);
}
```

They are used to encrypt the IP addresses of users in the database.
The $password parameter is stored in a php config file (so only dumping the sql will not give you the IP-s even when you know these functions).

I'm still puzzled over them as MD5 is clearly hashing and only things like bruteforcing can reverse it.

Can someone with more php experience explain, how this decryption works? The encrypted text is not a simple MD5 so I might have to understand what is happening there.

Anyway I'm trying to write a mysql stored function doing the decryption, because I want to join an other table by the IP-s (a table containing IP ranges for countries), and only return the country codes in the query.

The problems are: I have never written a MySQL function. How do I make a while cycle? there are functions like pack, and preg_replace which are not built in in MySQL, do I have to implement them too somehow?

Any help would be appreciated (ranging from hints to the full function)!

Comments like "MD5 cannot be decrypted it's hashing!" will not be appreciated.

Comment: md5 is only used on the IV - the encryption itself seems to be some sort of XOR...

Comment: You really need encryption? Such reversible schemes are not safe (from the security standpoint) Hashing may more secure if the only thing you want is comparing IP addresses, and MySQL already has many functions for hashing.

Comment: you didn't posted the full code. Here is the full code: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/md5-based-block-cipher.htm

Comment: Sawny: thanks for this link. Somehow the get_rnd_iv was lost in copypasta. @Paulo Scardine: That way I would need to brute force through every IP to check what IP range the current hash is in.

Comment: Wow, a self designed cipher based on a hash, inluding self designed padding and key stream. Funny thing is, it *might* actually be secure, at first sight I don't see any huge problems (outside the fact that it *is* an algorith, and the first rule of crypto is: don't create your own algorithm (implementations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these functions `md5` is only used to compute hash of constant component `$iv_len`, that is later used like salt to the passwords.

Every other operations are reversible (string padding, packing and XOR [`^`])

As for MySQL function, I wouldn't do it. IMHO better solution is to extend users table with `country_from_ip` column and populate it from php, by decrypting all existing IPs and getting their country code and modifying php code to add this info while saving new record.

Making a join on field computed by function will very soon become bottleneck for your application

Comment: Yes I think this would be the best solution. I'm about to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 hash isn't performed on the IP address, it appears to be used to add some random seed data to the encryption, or something.

As for how to decrypt it, why do you want to use SQL? While is probably possible, I suspect PHP is much faster at this type of operation.

Use SQL to select, say, 1000 user rows at a time, and then use PHP to actually link them against each country.

Comment: the ipranges-countries are stored in the database, and I don't want to run a query for every single IP address. and I don't know about mysql function speeds, but in my experience returning a query and after transforming every record and run a query on each of them is usually bad practice if you can make the transformation in sql. but if you tell me that this is a bad idea I may have to believe you. just seemed an interesting problem.